# imageview transition to another activity that provides imageview also but with zooming functionality

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imageview, android-transitions

I have imageview in **Activity A** onclick will take me to another activity (**Activity B)** that will only have imageview but with zooming functionality.

So I want onclick of imageview in Activity A to **make a transitional effect** to the imageview in Activity B that has the zooming functionality. The same way facebook application does with its images.

I have successfully made what I need but without transitional effect which is really bad UX.

What I have tried:

1) Tried the [DevBytes: Custom Activity Animations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA)
 but it is just animation with no zooming effect. I modified it so that in activity B I have imageview with zoomable functionality (I used this library: [ZoomableImageView](https://github.com/laurencedawson/ZoomableImageView)) but then all I got when transition finishes is black shadow with no image.

2) Tried the new ActivityCompatOptions api but no transitional effect happened(it turned out it is not supported for pre-L devices).

All I want is something similar to what facebook app do when image is clicked.

Comment: any answers for this question?

Comment: did you find any solutions?